# ' HTTP Status 500 - Unable to find taglib "s" for URI: /struts-tags ' Error when I deploy war file on Ubuntu server

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, tomcat, struts2

I have developed maven project with *Struts2*. I run it on *Apache Tomcat 8.5.5* server. The war file of the project is working fine on localhost. But it gives an error when I deploy the war file on Ubuntu server.

I have read some articles and they have advised to check whether I add struts2-core jar file or not. But I have added struts2-core-2.5.2.jar already.

Looking for some suggestions to solve this

[image]

pom.xml

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.projectTest</groupId>
 <artifactId>webplatform</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>projectA</name>

 <properties>
  <struts2.version>2.5.2</struts2.version>
  <log4j2.version>2.5</log4j2.version>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
   <version>${struts2.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${struts2.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-junit-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>${struts2.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
   <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
   <version>4.5</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>tech.sqldao</groupId>
   <artifactId>sql_dao</artifactId>
   <version>0.3.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
   <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
   <version>10.13.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>6.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jgeppert.struts2.bootstrap</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-bootstrap-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts2-json-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.5.8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
   <version>20030203.000129</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.hynnet</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts.xwork</groupId>
   <artifactId>xwork-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.32</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javamail</groupId>
   <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
   <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
   <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.10</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <finalName>ProjectA</finalName>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
     <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
     <source>1.5</source>
     <target>1.5</target>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>

   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
     <server>TomcatServer</server>     
     <username>xxxxx</username>
     <password>xxxxx</password>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
    <configuration>
     <stopKey>CTRL+C</stopKey>
     <stopPort>8999</stopPort>
     <systemProperties>
      <systemProperty>
       <name>xwork.loggerFactory</name>
       <value>com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.log4j2.Log4j2LoggerFactory</value>
      </systemProperty>
     </systemProperties>
     <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
     <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</webAppSourceDirectory>
     <webAppConfig>
      <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
     </webAppConfig>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Edited my question with an image of the error page.

Comment: Post text, not images; that's text. Suggestions? Make sure you're deploying what you think you are. Make sure your DTD is correct. Other than that it's difficult to help w/ the information provided.

Comment: please show us some code and your pom file with the dependencies you have. there is too much missing info here to answer.